# Problems with relative module urls when using serviceworker fallback handlers

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

When using svelte kit in conjunction with a service worker configuration to return a fallback route while offline,
for each request `/test/` the service worker will respond with prerendered html for `/` (fallback-route).
if we look inside the prerendered html we see modules beeing preloaded with relative urls:

```
<link rel="modulepreload" href="./_app/immutable/start-5e8ef69f.js">
<link rel="modulepreload" href="./_app/immutable/chunks/index-cc4e69a6.js">
<link rel="modulepreload" href="./_app/immutable/chunks/stores-e8997401.js">
<link rel="modulepreload" href="./_app/immutable/chunks/preload-helper-b21cceae.js">
<link rel="modulepreload" href="./_app/immutable/chunks/store-535059b2.js">
```

the problem here is that the browser resolved these urls to `/test/_app/immutable/start-5e8ef69f.js, etc...` and won't find these assets. if these urls would be absolute this problem would not exist. is this by design or am i doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it using out using the `kit.config.paths.assets`. configuration option in `svelte.config.js`.
setting it will prepend all paths.